# How to escape characters when assigning to type char (not String) in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, escaping, char

I was reading similar to [this discussion](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/108805-single-vs-double-quotes.html) here on SO last week and now I have the problem I can't find that thread.

I need to assign the double quote character " to a variable of type `wchar_t`, I use

```
wchar_t atest = '"';
wchar_t atest2 = '\"';
```

In the VS debugger `atest` is shown as `34 L'"'` (now I see where the quotes separate) and `atest2` is `38 L'&'`. I understand which to use now but not why. What is happening when I create `atest2`?

Comment: The second is `34 L'"'` for me (MSVC 2010)

Comment: Doh! Sorry, I was looking at the other variable being compared! You are right I am wrong.

Comment: You might want to write `L'"'` or `L'\"'`, so it's explicitly of type `wchar_t`.  It's not really necessary, though, since the `char` value will be promoted.

Comment: @John: You've accepted an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a multi-character constant.  They are legal per the C(++) specifications but their interpretation is implementation-defined.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx) for a little bit of detail, but in short: don't do that.

Comment: No, `'\"'` is not a multi-character constant.  See my answer, and section 2.13.2 of the 2003 C++ standard.

Comment: @Keith: Yes, you're right, I remembered that `\\` is a no-op for non-escape sequences after I wrote this answer.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

```
wchar_t atest = '"';
wchar_t atest2 = '\"';
```

These two are equivalent.

Certain characters have to be escaped in character literals, including `\` itself, so a backslash character is `'\\'`.

The double-quote character can *optionally* be escaped.  Presumably this is for consistency with string literals, where they *must* be escaped.  Similarly, the single-quote character must be escaped in character literals, and may be escaped in string literals.

(No, `'\"'` is not a multi-character constant.)